# Getting an error when trying to query the installations of add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

**Goal:**

I have a public Google Workspace Marketplace editor add-on for Google Forms.
I would like to query the installations and uninstallations via the Google Workspace Marketplace API within Google Apps Script.

**Approach:**

- I have created a new Google Apps Script and linked it to the same GCP project as the add-on is hosted
- My understanding is that when making the request to the Google Workspace Marketplace API from the script with my own user, it is going to use the OAuth consent screen and the corresponding scopes of the add-on. Thus resulting in an error. For this reason I need to use a service account to make the API request and to use separate scopes.
- I am using the Compute Engine default service account. I have already enabled domain-wide delegation and the Google Workspace Marketplace OAuth Client for this service account.
- Last but not least I have created a service account key file in JSON format and copy/pasted the content into my script.

**Script:**

```
const serviceAccount = {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "<<MY PROJECT ID>>",
  "private_key_id": "<<MY PRIVATE KEY>>",
  "private_key": "<<MY PRIVATE KEY>>",
  "client_email": "<<MY CLIENT EMAIL>>",
  "client_id": "<<MY CLIENT ID>>",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "<<MY CERT URL>>"
};

const { private_key, client_email, project_id } = serviceAccount;

const createService = (name, serviceAccount, scopes, userToImpersonate) => {
  return OAuth2.createService(name)
    .setSubject(userToImpersonate)
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
    .setPrivateKey(serviceAccount.private_key)
    .setIssuer(serviceAccount.client_email)
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
    .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
    .setLock(LockService.getUserLock())
    .setScope(scopes);
};

const sendRequest = (url, oauthParams) => {
  const { serviceName, serviceAccount, scopes, userToImpersonate } =
    oauthParams;

  const oauthService = createService(
    serviceName,
    serviceAccount,
    scopes,
    userToImpersonate
  );

  if (!oauthService.hasAccess()) {
    console.log('ERROR IS ' + oauthService.getLastError());
    return;
  }

  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${oauthService.getAccessToken()}`,
  };

  const options = {
    method: 'get',
    headers,
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };

  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
};

const getLicenseNotifications = () => {
  const url = 'https://appsmarket.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/licenseNotification/<<MY APP ID>>?maxResults=2';
  const oauthParams = {
    serviceName: 'GWMservice',
    serviceAccount,
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license'],
    userToImpersonate: '<<MY USER>>@<<MY DOMAIN>>.com',
  };

  console.log(sendRequest(url, oauthParams));
};
```

**Google Apps Script manifest:**

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "OAuth2",
        "version": "43",
        "libraryId": "1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ]
}
```

**Error:**

I am receiving the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 503,
    "message": "Temporary error. Please try later.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Temporary error. Please try later.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "backendError"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a case of [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/reference/rest/v2/licenseNotification/list) being **wrong** (as of April 8th, 2023). The `maxResults` parameter is actually expressed as `max-results` and the same applies to `start-token`. Once you change the query parameter retrieval (and pagination) should work.

Answer (score 0):

The `HTTP status code of 503` usually indicates that the API quotas have been exceeded. The Google Documentation says:

> For all errors that are time based (maximum of N things for X seconds per thread), especially the 503 status code errors, we recommend your code catch the exception and, using an [exponential backoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_binary_exponential_backoff) algorithm, wait for a small delay before retrying the failed call.

You can read this information [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/limits).

You can see the quota limit under the [GCP](https://console.cloud.google.com/) console, and follow the steps:

1. Open Menu.
2. Select "APIs & Services."
3. Click on "Enable APIs & services."

[image]

4. Search for the "Google Workspace Marketplace API" in the list, and click on it.
5. Select "Quota."

[image]

The quota limits will show up there, you can set the exponential backoff base on that information. Lastly, as a last resources if you have a Google Workspace account you can [contact support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) to help you review the quota limits.

**Reference:**

- [Usage Limits.](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/limits)
- [Troubleshoot error codes.](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/troubleshoot-error-codes)
- [503 Service Unavailable Error.](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Apigee/503-Service-unavailable-error/m-p/32057/highlight/true#M26116)
- [Contact Google Workspace support.](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213)

Comment: It seems that the quotas are not exceeded, I have checked them within the GCP console. I have the impression that the error message and code are misleading and the real cause has to do with authentication.

Comment: Is the request too long maybe, that was also in the reference links documentation. If that is not the case, I will say to contact Google Workspace since the 5XX HTTP status code might be a server error. If the issue was authentication, it will show a 4XX HTTP status code.